# Conditional rendering React issue (loop)

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to use forEach or map functions with no success (had xxx is not a function errors). Decided to go with good old for loop but instead of creating multiple div elements my program only renders one.

Simplified example:

```
getTest(){
    const l = this.props.renderedDrugs.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < l; i++){
        return <div>{this.props.renderedDrugs[i].id}</div>
    }
}

render() {

    const test = (this.props.renderedDrugs) ? this.getTest() : nope()

    function nope(){
        return 'nope'
    }
    return (
        <div>{test}</div>
    )
}
}
```

No matter what I do I cant return multiple divs, have no problems with multiple console logs though. Am I missing something crucial from basic react functions that I completely forgot because of staring at the screen like a moron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do want `map`:

```
getTest() {
    return this.props.renderedDrugs.map(rd => <div>{rd.id}</div>)
}
```

The reason only one renders is because `return <div>{this.props.renderedDrugs[i].id}</div>`, ya know, returns that value from the function. `map` is a lot cleaner but you can emulate map with your for loop and an array:

```
getTest(){
    const l = this.props.renderedDrugs.length;
    const ary = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < l; i++){
        ary.push(<div>{this.props.renderedDrugs[i].id}</div>);
    }
    return ary;
}
```

Comment: I'd love to use a map, atlhough i keep getting 'this.props.renderedDrugs.map is not a function' and cant fix that

Comment: Then `this.props.renderedDrugs` is not an array.

Comment: @MazMat edited answer that shows you how to build an array from a `for` loop.

Comment: This works for me, thank you, I completely forgot you cant map through objects